# Adding my existing video to my YouTube channel

Tags: youtube

Visiting my YouTube channel there are two tabs: `Feed` and `Video`.

It seems the Feed tab is displayed by default.

Trouble is, the feed does not display all of my public videos. They were probably uploaded before I explicitly created the channel.

How do I get my channel to display all my public videos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feed is, well your feed. It displays basically your activity. If you like a video it will appear in that feed saying you liked xyz video.

If you don't want the feed to be the default option that appears you can go into the settings when on your video channels page and check `Enable featured tab`*. This will make a featured video appear and videos uploaded appear below (of course only public ones).

Comment: That did it to change the default tab, thank you. I thought the "channel" was something more specifically with one's latest videos by default.

Comment: No problem. If you need any more help later relating to YouTube or any web apps kind of thing don't hesitate to ask another question :)